# how should I configure "block public access" on Amazon S3?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, amazon-iam

I am using paper clip and ruby on rails to upload images from my website to AWS S3 and my webapp is hosted on heroku. Should I checking block public access under bucket settings?

Currently I have BLOCK ALL PUBLIC ACCESS and I can't upload the images. When I uncheck block all public access, I am able to do it. What should I be setting for S3 in order for my heroku image uploading app to work?

Answer (score 0):

Change your bucket policy like this and try

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "S3Permissions",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your app on Heroku does, but I would think, the Heroku app would use IAM credentials to talk to S3. And you need to create the IAM user in the account where the S3 bucket is, with S3 put actions.